# My code is janky, it is an animation slider does anyone know how to make it smoother, transistions don't do the job properly

Tags: html, css

Hello i am new to css and html, andi have encountered a problem. The animation is fast when it starts, but when it adds more images it becomes slower, and starts to pause in mid-way, it tried reducing the pixels of the image and it is still slow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main-image">
      <div class="real-img">
        <img class="image-scale" src="images/realimg.jpg" alt="" /> 
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="main-image">
      <div class="real-img">
        <h1 class="image-scale">Build Your Generation</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-image">
      <div class="real-img">
        <div class="search-box">
          <input class= "search-txt" type="text" placeholder="    Search" name = "q">
          <button class= "search-icon"><a href="#"><img src="images/searchicon.svg" alt=""></a></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  -
    <div class="img_container animate zoom-in-out">
      <div class="images animate--speed1 animate slidert">
        <img class="img" src="images/Img1.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images2  animate slider-2">
        <img class="img" src="images/Img2.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images animate--speed  animate slidermt">
        <img class="img" src="images/Img3.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images2  animate slider-2">
        <img class="img" src="images/img4.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images animate--speed1 animate slidert">
        <img class="img" src="images/img5.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images animate slider">
        <img class="img" src="images/img6.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images2 animate slider-2">
        <img class="img" src="images/img7.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images  animate--speed4 animate slidert">
        <img class="img" src="images/img8.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images2 animate slider-2">
        <img class="img" src="images/img9.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images">
        <img class="img" src="images/img10.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images  animmate slider">
        <img class="img" src="images/img11.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images2 animate--speed3 animate slider-2t">
        <img class="img" src="images/img12.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images animate--speed3  animate slidert">
        <img class="img" src="images/mainimg13.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images2 animate--speed3  slider-2t">
        <img class="img" src="images/img14.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images">
        <img class="img" src="images/img15.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images  animate slider">
        <img class="img" src="images/img16.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images2 animate--speed2 animate slider-2t">
        <img class="img" src="images/img17.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images  animate slider">
        <img class="img" src="images/img18.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images2 animate--speed2 animate slider-2t">
        <img class="img" src="images/img19.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images">
        <img class="img" src="images/img20.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images  animate slider">
        <img class="img" src="images/img21.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images2 animate--speed1 animate slider-2t">
        <img class="img" src="images/img22.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images  animate slider">
        <img class="img" src="images/img23.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images2 animate--speed1 animate slider-2t">
        <img class="img" src="images/img24.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="images   animate slider">
        <img class="img" src="images/img25.jpg" alt="" />
      </div>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

```
*{
   font-size: 16px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

body{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    
}

.img_container{
 margin-top: 2rem;
 display: grid;
 align-items: center;
 grid-template-columns: 20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
 grid-template-rows:  20% 20% 20% 20% 20%;
 gap: 0.5rem;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 animation: disappear 2s ease 1s forwards;
 

}

.images{
    height: 20vh;
    width: 20vw;
    position: relative;
    top: 1000px;
}
.images2{
    height: 20vh;
    width: 20vw;
    position: relative;
    top: -700px;

}



.img{
    height: 100px;
    width:  200px;
    object-fit: cover;

   
}
.animate--speed{
   animation-duration: 2.7s;
   animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);

}

.animate--speed1{
   animation-duration: 1.7s;
   

}

.animate--speed2{
    animation-duration: 2.1s;
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  
}

.animate--speed3{
   animation-duration: 2.7s;
   animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.55, 0.085, 0.68, 0.53);
  
}



.animate--speed4{
   animation-duration: 2.1s;
   animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
}

.animate-quick{
    animation-delay: 1.4s;
}

@keyframes slider{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
         object-fit: cover;
    }
    25%{
        opacity: 0;

    }
    100%{object-fit: cover;
        opacity: 1;
        top: 0px;
         object-fit: cover;
    }
}
@keyframes slider-2{
    0%{

        object-fit: cover;
   }
   25%{
    
       object-fit: cover;
   }
   100%{
        opacity: 1;
        top:0px;
        object-fit: cover;
   }
}

.slidermt{
    animation-name: slider;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.slidert{
    animation-name: slider;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  
    
}
.slider-2t{
    animation-name: slider-2;
    animation-delay: 2s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 
}

.zoom-in-out{
   animation: zoom-in-out 5s 4.8s backwards;
}


@keyframes zoom-in-out{
    0%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(1.5,1.5);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(5,5);
    }
}
@keyframes zoom-in-out2{
    0%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50%{
        transform: scale(0.7,0.7);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}

.main-image{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: 999999;
}

.real-img{
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 999999;

    animation: resize 2s ease-in-out 7.5s forwards;
}


.image-scale{
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    object-fit: cover;

    animation: resize 2s ease-in-out 7.5s forwards;
    
}

h1{
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3rem;
    z-index: 999999;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    top: 30%;
}

.search-box{
    position: relative;
    background: #221d22;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 2rem;
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 37%;
}

.search-txt{
    
    height: 2rem;
    width: 350px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}
input{
   
    background: #221d22;
    border: #b6b6b6;
    color: #ececec;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 0;
    outline: none;
}

.search-icon{
    height: 2rem;
    background-color: #221d22;
    border-radius: 16px;
    display: flex;
    float: right;
    align-items: center;
    outline: none;
    border: none;

    
}

.search-icon:hover{
    background-color: #1a6d12;
}

@keyframes  resize{
   from{
    opacity: 0;
       object-fit: cover;
   }
   to{ 
      opacity: 1;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    
   }

}



.main-img{
    height: 20vh;
    width: 20vw;
    position: relative;
    top: 1000px;
    animation: slider 2.8s 1s forwards;
}
@keyframes disappear{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}
```

I am copying an animation from,https://camillemormal.com/  to challenge myself, i am trying to get that smooth effect the website has